# My account is mixed up with another user

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management

Every time I log into my Gmail account using my correct email address, my husband's name is attached to it. My husband is a Yahoo! user.  We use the same computer, but this error just started happening recently.  When I email someone from my Gmail account, it appears that the email is sent by my husband. He said he don't think he click on anything to have made this happen.  I have tried the recovery page 4 times and shutting computer down.

Comment: Make sure you have not linked both account to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there was a mix-up on a different browser or device. To test this:

- On the gmail web page select `account` from the 3x3 dots at the top right.
- Then under `Sign in & Security` (left column) check the 3 options but especially the last 2:

  - Device activity & security events
  - Apps with account access

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your husband's address has been linked to Gmail and set as default.
To check that, go to  `Settings > Accounts and Import > Send mail as:`.
If in the list there is an address different from yours, make your own the default and delete the other(s).

Note that it's nearly impossible to add a different address to your account by mistake, and it requires knowledge of both your account and the one to add (you can read more about that at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370).

Maybe you or your husband was trying to configure automatic forwarding and picked the wrong section.

If that's the goal, see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957 to forward from Google.

Looks like forwarding from Yahoo has been disabled (see https://my.help.yahoo.com/kb/new-mail-for-desktop/automatic-forwarding-emails-free-yahoo-mail-accounts-discontinued-sln35503.html).